# 「おはつよろ」のいみはなんですか？

Tags: words, internet-slang, abbreviations

「おはつよろ」のいみはなんですか？　I was interacting on a chat and after providing greetings, I used hajimemashite and yoroshiku onegaishimasu and I received ohatsuyoro as a response. I was unable to find the word(s) in a dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an internet slang. おはつ means 初めまして and よろ means よろしくお願いします.

Comment: Is it common in spoken conversation?

Comment: No. This is an internet slang. You had better not use it in real life.